# NSString - Truncate everything after decimal point in a double

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, double, truncate

I have a double that I need only the value of everything before the decimal point.

Currently I am using

```
NSString *level = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",doubleLevel];
```

but when given a value of 9.96, this returns "10".  So it is rounding.  I need it to return only the "9". (note - when the value is 9.95, it correctly returns the "9" value.)

Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Comment: assign you double value directly to int. and try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign the float/double value to a int value.

```
int intValue = doubleLevel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast that baby as an int.

```
int castedDouble = doubleLevel;
```

Anything after the `.` in the double will be truncated.

`9.1239809384 --> 9`

`123.90454980 --> 123`

No rounding, simple truncation.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *level = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",doubleLevel];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it as a float:

```
CGFloat f = 9.99;
f = floorf(f);
```

there are quite a variety of `floor` and `round` implementations.
they have been around since UN*X, and are actually part of those low-level libraries, be they BSD, Posix, or some other variety - you should make yourself familiar with them.

there are different versions for different "depths" of floating point variables.